# How do I access a specifing key in an array using variable variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, dynamic-variables

My problem is so twisted that I don't even know how to start to explain it.

Lets say that I have several assosiative arrays (not always the same arrays: sometimes I have the products array, sometimes I have the markets array, sometimes I have the segment array, etc...). $values is the only array I always get!

```
$values = array ("0" => "1", "4" => "2", "5" => "3");
$products = array ("0" => "1", "1" => "1", "2" => "2", "3" => "1", "4" => "2", "5" => "3");
$markets =  array ("0" => "1",  "3" => "1", "4" => "2", "5" => "3");
...
```

I want to build an array with the values of each of the arrays I get, with the values matching the keys.
Something like

```
$myArray = array ("0" => array ( "values" => "1", "products" => "1", "markets" => "1"),
                  "1" => array ( "products" => "1"),
                  "2" => array ( "products" => "2"),
                  "3" => array ( "products" => "1", "markets" => "1"),
                  "4" => array ( "values" => "2", "products" => "2", "markets" => 2),
                ...);
```

I've tried something like this:

```
        switch ($_POST["cpv_type"]) {
            case "pClass":
                $keyValue = $_POST["cpv_type"];
                $objKey   = "this->productClasses";
                break;

            case "pMarket":
                $keyValue = $_POST["cpv_type"];
                $objKey   = "this->markets";
                break;

            case "pSegment":
                $keyValue = $_POST["cpv_type"];
                $objKey   = "this->productSegments";
                break;

            case "pType":
                $keyValue = $_POST["cpv_type"];
                $objKey   = "this->productTypes";
                break;

            default:
                $keyValue = "products";
                $objKey = "this->products";
                break;
        }
```

And then I do a foreach cicle:

```
    // all values must be floats
    if(!empty($this->value)){
        foreach ($this->value as $key => &$curVal){
            // if no value has been entered, exclude it and also associated product from validation
            if (strlen(trim($curVal)) == 0) {
                unset($this->value[$key]);
                unset($this->products[$key]);
            } else {
                                        // This validates my variable 
                $curVal =   TMS::checkVar($curVal, "dec", $_SESSION["dico"]->_VALUE_, 100, false);


                                        // Store the value on existing array, associating "hoppValue" to the right key entry!
                $logDetail[$keyValue][${$objKey}[$key]]["hoppValue"] = $curVal;
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is in the variable variable:
How do I access, for example `$this->productTypes[5]` using variable variable syntax?
I get "null" for all var_dumps of `$$objKey`, `${$objKey}`, `${$objKey}[$key]`, `${$objKey[$key]}`, `$$objKey[$key]`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can simple get array in case ` $objKey   = $this->productClasses` and used  as `$objKey[$key]`

Comment: You are totally right!
The answer was so simple and right in front of my eyes. Workdays shouldn't be so long!

(Please put your comment into answer so I mark it right!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple get array in case `$objKey = $this->productClasses` and used as `$objKey[$key]`. And you can replace `$objKey` to `$arrayClasses` or similary for good understending code.

p.s. sorry for my English.